# SSH client: port knocking (execute command before connecting)

Tags: ssh, security

How can I have a port knocking sequence (or a command that does the port knocking) executed prior to trying to establish an SSH connection?

Preferably using the pre-installed `ssh` command, but also willing to switch if there's no "standard alternative".

Comment: Use bash functions or alias.

Comment: **Attention Close voters:** Port knocking as to open a number of ports and close them again before a daemon will "answer" on the regular port...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also try to use the option [ProxyCommand](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand).

It gives you the ability to control the command used to connect to the server; sounds troublesome, but I haven't found any problem with it yet.

From the [ssh_config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) docs:

> ##### ProxyCommand
>
> Specifies the command to use to connect to the server.  The command string extends to the end of the line, and is executed using the user's shell ‘exec’ directive to avoid a
> lingering shell process.
>
> In the command string, any occurrence of `%h` will be substituted by the host name to connect, `%p` by the port, and `%r` by the remote user name.  The command can be basically
> anything, and should read from its standard input and write to its standard output.  It should eventually connect an [sshd(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8) server running on some machine, or execute `sshd -i`
> somewhere.  Host key management will be done using the `HostName` of the host being connected (defaulting to the name typed by the user).  Setting the command to `none` disables
> this option entirely.  Note that `CheckHostIP` is not available for connects with a proxy command.
>
> This directive is useful in conjunction with [nc(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/nc.1) and its proxy support.  For example, the following directive would connect via an HTTP proxy at 192.0.2.0:
>
> ```
> ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X connect -x 192.0.2.0:8080 %h %p
> ```

## Example

Lets say you have a command or script that does the knocking IN YOUR PATH: `knock.sh <host> <port1 port2 ... portX>`

And you want to connect to some host: `myhost.net`

You can add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host thehost
    HostName myhost.net              
    ProxyCommand bash -c 'knock.sh %h <port1 port2 ... portX>; nc %h %p'
```

- %h => the hostname (myhost.net)
- %p => the port (22)

And you can connect to your host with: `ssh user@thehost`

You should also be able to use the option directly from the command line with:
`ssh -o ProxyCommand="bash -c 'knock.sh %h <port1 port2 ... portX>; nc %h %p'" user@myhost.net`

### Notes

If the program writes data to stdout by default it gets hidden, if you need to see it, add `-v` after `ssh`.

Also note that `ssh` has to execute the knocking before performing the connection, so the total time it will take to complete the connection will be greater.

I have a current configuration working with port forwarding enabled and no problem with it yet.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to feeding all traffic through `nc` as a ProxyCommand, as in the accepted answer, is to add a `Match host/exec` line to ~/.ssh/config that effectively only executes your `knock` command before connecting:

```
Match host thehost exec "knock -d 500 %h 1234 5678"
Match host thehost.domain.com exec "knock -d 500 %h 1234 5678"
```

This line doesn't actually do anything else than executing `knock`, since there's nothing following the directive.

**update**

To make the knock conditional (and prevent the delay and a ton of redundant firewall rules), probe using netcat before knocking:

```
Match host thehost exec "nc -zw 3 %h 22 || knock -d 500 %h 1234 5678"
Match host thehost.domain.com exec "nc -zw 3 %h 22 || knock -d 500 %h 1234 5678"
```

The `-w 3` flag is to specify a timeout of 3 seconds for the probe.

**updated to take comments of Adrien into account**

Comment: This seems like a workaround of the `Match exec` feature. But it is really helpful. To be more precise, the `Match exec` will tell ssh that the configured section can be used if and only if the command return a 0 exit code.

Comment: **Beware**: The `Match exec` directive will replace the `Host` section for matching. So you need the following: `Match originalhost thehost exec "nc -zw 3 %h 22 || knock -d 500 %h 1234 5678"`

Comment: Good catch. My indenting is clearly off; the Match directive here is not part of the preceding Host directive.

Comment: This seems to work great, but I can't execute an interactive command with `exec` , and ideas/help? I've posted here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1117873/ssh-config-how-to-automatically-execute-an-interactive-script-locally-before-co

Answer (score 3):

According to [an Ubuntu help page on port knocking](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortKnocking#Client_Side), you can do the following:

1. Install the `knock` program by running `sudo apt-get install knockd`
2. Make a script in `~/bin` to establish the SSH connection for the particular server:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   knock hostname port1 port2 port3...
   ssh hostname
   ```
3. Make the script executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/whatever`
4. Close the terminal, reopen it, and run `whatever`

Comment: meh, I kind of dislike the idea of having to resort to an alias or writing a script to accomplish this, but if there's no other way of doing it, alright. Thanks!